# Is following differential equation non linear equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the following equation:
$$yy^\prime=0$$

Is above equation non linear?
I think it is linear because the above equation can be reduced to $$y^\prime=0.$$ Am I correct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By the definition it is non linear. What you have done is correct only when $y \not\equiv 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it stands it is considered as non-linear because LHS is not linear in $y$. (The equation is equivalent to $(y^{2})'=0$ so $y^{2}=c$ and the only continuous function satisfying the equation are constants. ).

Comment: Thanks sir! How do you say that the equation is nonlinear?

Comment: A linear ODE is defined as an equation of the type $L(y,y',...,y^{n)})=f$ where $L: \mathbb R^{n} \to \mathbb R$ is a linear function.

Comment: So to find if an equation is non linear or linear one should not transform that equation? Similarly the equation sin(y')=x is a nonlinear differential equation right? Because if this transformed to another equation $y^{\prime}=sin^{-1} x$ which is linear.

Comment: Yes, that is the convention that is generally followed by Mathematicians.

Comment: Incidentally the equation says either $y=0$ or $y'=0$ at each point. At some points we may have $y=0$ and at others we may have $y'=0$. So you have to do some extra work before you find all solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that 
$$\frac{1}{2} \, \frac{d}{dx} ( y^2) = 0 $$
is the same as $y \, y' = 0$. The "solution" is
\begin{align}
y \, y' &= 0 \\
\frac{1}{2} \, \frac{d}{dx} \, y^2 &= 0 \\ 
y^2 &= c_{1}^{2} \\
y(x) &= c_{0} = \pm c_{1}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! So is the equation is linear or non-linear?

Comment: @shwetha The equation in non-linear.